# Can't import static library header files

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

Hi My app storyboard works and I can link the custom class of my **MainProject Storyboard** to **Static Library ViewController** but my problem is when i try to  use **#import** from my MainProject to locate for header files, my header files in my Static library doesn't show up.

here's my project settings(SecondSample is my Static Library)

[image]

My MainProject header search path

[image]

My Static Library build setting

[image]

I hope someone can help me with my issue. Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:** I didn't copy my static library to my MainProject folder... I've just add a reference to it.

Comment: Unlike framework, with static lib you need to have the header as well.

Comment: My static library has header.. and I can use it via Storyboard of my mainApp but when I call the header of my staticLibrary from my mainapp it doesnt recognize it

Comment: I have had to use a path rather than just the header file name with static libs in XCode.  YMMV.